# jpa how to fetch namedEntityGraph on detached entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

What is the best way to do additional work on detached entities?

Some context...

I am currently fetching the user in a Filter for my REST services. In some cases, I need work with some lazy collections on the User entity. What is the best way to do this?

I am currently calling entityManager.merge, and then calling the getCollection method.

UserService:

```
public class UserService {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public boolean doWork(User user) { // user is detached when passed in
        user = entityManager.merge(user);
        for (Entity e: user.getLazyCollection() {
            // doWork
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please write a jpql query to load the entity graph don't reattach the user entity this is not good for performance if you aren't going to persist the user entity later, here you have and small example about how to work with entity graphs http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

Comment: @karelss thats what I suspected was the best thing to do. Thanks!